# Monkeyrunner для ручного тестировщика

Tags: android, python, тестирование

Хотел написать автоматический скрипт, используя [*Monkeyrunner*](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html), но нигде не нашёл инструкцию по использованию для **тестировщиков**. На том же хабре как и везде работа с *monkeyrunner* описывается глазами программиста для программистов.
Может есть пример пошаговой установки всего этого дела и примера работы с *monkeyrunner* для **ручного** тестировщика, который пытается познать автоматизацию мобилок ?

Comment: Я бы попробовал Селениум. Он делает то же, что и Манкираннер, только распространённее и проще – можно писать тесты без кода, с помощью [плагина для браузера](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/plugins.jsp).

Comment: Для "установки" рекомендовал бы использовать докер. "Примеры для работы" думаю придется поднять скилл в питоне и работать с примера для программистов.